# MS Access: Updating column in existing table based on two variables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to update an existing table (table 1) based on two variables. The existing table is a health care dataset that shows patient admit, consult, and discharge dates. I have a separate dataset (table 2) that has more consult dates to add. So, I would like to upload/update the consult date from table 2 into table 1 by matching the patient ID number and admission date.

I have already created a query that merges table 1 and 2 successfully, but I am unable to edit any of the variables manually when I have merged them.

```
SELECT Inpatient.PatientID, Inpatient.AdmissionDate, Inpatient.Admit, FirstNote.ConsultDate, Inpatient.DischargeDate
FROM Inpatient INNER JOIN 
     FirstNote 
     ON (Inpatient.AdmissionDate = FirstNote.Admit) AND
        (Inpatient.PatientID = FirstNote.PatientID);
```

I expect the final table to have the following variables:
Patient ID, AdmissionDate, ConsultDate, DischargeDate

with updated data under ConsultDate from table 2

Comment: Really should not save this value into Table1 - it can be calculated when needed. Use DMax() function to pull the latest data in table 2 for each patient or build an aggregate query that pulls the Max date for each patient and join that query to table1. And if you must, run an UPDATE action using the DMax().

Comment: Or build a report using Sorting & Grouping features and textbox calc `=Max(ConsultDate)` in patient group footer.